# MYSQL query to find all rows that are outside join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query which will return all rows of a table CLASSES that do not matched with another table named CHILD_CLASSES. These two tables look like this,

The table CLASSES is a self referencing table so the top CLASS does not have a parent_id. The Parent ID row is created from the class_id row. So when I inserted A1 as a sub class to A then its parent ID is 1 because A's class_id is 1. And then A11 is a sub class to A1 as well as A12 so their parent_ids will be 2.

```
CLASS_ID  |  PARENT_ID | CLASS_NAME
-----------------------------------
  1       |     --     |    A
  2       |     1      |    A1
  3       |     2      |    A11
  4       |     2      |    A12
```

I then have another table CHILD_CLASSES which will store the children of each CLASS. Since A is the top Class it will have the children of everything below it, A1, A11, and A12. A1 will only have A11 and A12. It looks like this

```
ID   | PARENT_ID | CLASS_ID
----------------------------
  1  |     1     |    2
  2  |     1     |    3
  3  |     1     |    4
  5  |     2     |    3
  6  |     2     |    4
```

This is a little archaic but all I am really looking for is a query that will return to me the rows in the CLASSES table that do not have children for a given CLASS_ID. For example, if I run the query on A1 which is class_id 2, it will return to me rows with the class_ids of 1 because the CLASS A is CLASS that has not been set as a child of A1 in the CHILD_CLASSES table. If I were to run the query on A11 then I would get class_ids 1, 2, and 4 because A1 has no children yet, and so on. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    classes c
WHERE   class_id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  class_id
        FROM    child_classes cc
        WHERE   cc.parent_id = 2
        )
        AND class_id <> 2
```

Comment: @Fred: `classes` corrected. As for the `SELECT` clause, the question reads "the rows in the `CLASSES` table that do not have children for a given `CLASS_ID`".

Comment: ok ok but mysql_quest said: " If I were to run the query on A11 then I would get class_ids 1, 2, and 4 because A1 has no children yet, and so on. Any help would be much appreciated. "

Comment: Your second select doesn't seem to work, it returns only 2 instead of 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

Correction of Quassnoi request:

```
SELECT  class_id 
FROM    CLASSES c 
WHERE   c.class_id NOT IN 
        ( 
        SELECT  cc.class_id
        FROM    CHILD_CLASSES cc 
        WHERE   cc.parent_id = 2 
        ) 
        AND c.class_id <> 2
```

Comment: Indeed, MySQL will handle case differently on different platforms: on Windows, table names are case insensitive, while they are case sensitive on platforms like Linux.

Comment: I know it but corrections were not on table names. Quassnoi has made corrections on his post.

Answer (score 0):

This might be three years old, but it was in the vein of what I was doing today. The answers here were not very helpful to me at all. Thus, here is my method for an "OUTSIDE JOIN."

First, there is no such thing natively. That's why you're here. However, it's really simple and you don't need sub-queries. (Sub-queries give me headaches unnecessarily.)

1. `LEFT JOIN` the two tables you want to compare
2. A `NULL` value will show up in slots where there was nothing to match up
3. Ask for values `WHERE ____ IS NULL`

Your tables don't make much sense. I think you made a typo with "A1" instead of "A11," So I'll first provide my own for the sake of clarity. Here's a table of hierarchical body parts.

```
TABLE "Body_Parts"

id  |  parent  |  name
--------------------------
1   |   NULL   |  Torso
2   |    1     |  Arm
3   |    1     |  Leg
4   |    2     |  Hand
5   |    4     |  Finger
```

You might notice how the `Leg` currently has no children. Well, using only one table, you could see which items have no parent.

```
SELECT *
FROM Body_Parts AS side_A
LEFT JOIN Body_Parts AS side_B
ON side_A.parent = side_B.id -- bottom-up
WHERE side_B.id IS NULL

id  |  parent  |  name
--------------------------
1   |   NULL   |  Torso
```

Reversing the `ON` statement tells you which items have no children.

```
SELECT *
FROM Body_Parts AS side_A
LEFT JOIN Body_Parts AS side_B
ON side_A.id = side_B.parent -- top-down
WHERE side_B.id IS NULL

id  |  parent  |  name
--------------------------
3   |    1     |  Leg
5   |    4     |  Finger
```

Both of these examples can be modified to do the `LEFT JOIN` operation on two different tables instead of just one table. I'm just trying to make a point here. To address the OP's statement,

> This is a little archaic...

Yes, it is. It's smelly, and I don't think using two tables will benefit you in any way. You could have easily just used one table to track just one parent per class. If there could be multiple parents, you shouldn't have tracked the parent in the first table at all.